# Show only user related activity in a heartbeat view

Tags: 7, views, users, heartbeat

How do I create a heartbeat activity that shows only user related activity? For example, user 1 is related to user 2 and 3 (user relation module). When user 1 is logged in, he should be able to see activity only from user 2 and 3 and not from other users; similarly, it should happen for user 2 and 3. I'm logging the activity using the `heartbeat_api_log()` function.

**UPDATE**

The orthodox method of achieving this is to use [hook_heartbeat_related_uids()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--heartbeat--heartbeat.api.php/function/hook_heartbeat_related_uids/7).

It works fine, but in order to fine tune according to your own customizations you might want to use [hook_heartbeat_load()](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--heartbeat--heartbeat.api.php/function/hook_heartbeat_load/7), and remove unnecessary messages based on a condition you specify.

Comment: are you using 6 or 7?

Comment: 7 - sorry I didn't mention